# RxJS: How to ignore item in stream when outdated

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, reactive

I'm trying to subscribe to a "loading" Observable which returns a boolean. The goal is to have a delay for the items in the stream if loading is true, but not if loading is false. It should also be possible to ignore an outdated item, lets assume following case:

In the stream are two items:

- Item A with value true, and is passed immediately
- Item B with value false, and is passed 200ms later

Item A has value true, because of that it will be delayed by 500ms, Item B will not be delayed. In this situation Item B will arrive before Item A. I'm searching for an solution to completely ignore Item A for the mentioned case.

Here you see my current not-working solution:

```
this.loading$
        .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            delayWhen(loading => timer(loading ? 500 : 0))
        )
        .subscribe(loading => {
            // Do something
        });
```

Comment: You first say *"Item A with value true, and is passed immediately"* and in the next sentence *"Item A has value true, because of that it will be delayed by 500ms"*... I'm confused.

Comment: Item A comes first in the stream, but because of the delay of 500ms (see delayWhen -> timer(500)) the Item B will arrive faster (because it has no delay -> delayWhen -> timer(0)), in this case I would like to ignore Item A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `delayWhen` with `switchMap` and it should work. `switchMap` can cancel outdated inner stream. And you probably an one-time observable rather than an timer:

```
this.loading$
        .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(
               loading => 
                           of(loading).pipe(delay(loading ? 500 : 0)))
        )
        .subscribe(loading => {
            // Do something
        });
```